# Как сделать, чтобы screen в Linux Ubuntu не закрывался?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

Запускаю *php*-скрипт так:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -A -m -S mobiled su - www-data -c "php $DEMON_PATH/demon.php $1 $2 $3 $4 $5"
```

Все хорошо, но если скрипт завершается ошибкой, то в консоли только

> [screen is terminating]

Как сделать так, чтобы *screen* не закрывался?

Answer (score 1):

> Как сделать, чтобы screen не закрывался.

например, запустить какой-нибудь *shell* сразу же после команды.

---

пример.

допустим, интересующая нас команда, вывод которой мы не хотим терять — это `echo 123`. если запустить так:

```
$ screen echo 123
```

то *screen* тут же завершится и вывод команды (строка `123`) «сотрётся».

а если запустить так:

```
$ screen $SHELL -c "echo 123; $SHELL"
```

то сразу же по выполнении команды `echo 123` будет запущена программа, которую вы используете в качестве *shell*-а, *screen* **не** завершится и строка `123` останется на экране:

```
123
$
```

Answer (score 0):

как вариант перенаправить вывод в файл

```
screen -A -m -S mobiled su - www-data -c "php $DEMON_PATH/demon.php $1 $2 $3 $4 $5" `2>&1 >> $DEMON_PATH/daemon.log`
```